# How could I use Google Apps Script (Advanced Services) to create a Google BigQuery Dataset?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

The Google Apps "advanced services", as explained in the docs, are just wrappers to the associated Google APIs.

So for Create dataset API

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/insert

It takes one parameter:

```
project_id
```

It also takes a request body:

```
{
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset_id"
  }
}
```

So my Google Apps script would use the following code to pass the project_id in parameter

```
BigQuery.Datasets.insert(project_id);
```

But how could I pass the following request body to BigQuery.Datasets.insert?

```
{
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset_id"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resource = {
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset_id"
  }
};

BigQuery.Datasets.insert(resource, project)
```

OK. I should use the Google Apps Script auto complete feature to get the the function definition.

Note: These is no document for methods, such as BigQuery.Datasets.insert. It is based on the API reference document for the parameters, request and response. And I think the only way to get the Google Apps Script function definition is using the source editor's auto complete feature.

BigQuery.Datasets.insert's function is

```
BigQuery.Datasets.insert(resource, project)
```

And resource is the "request body".